# What should/can be learnt in a reading course on Elliptic Curves?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Currently, I am organizing a potential reading course on Elliptic Curves and have gotten some reference suggestions (I will be a student participating in said course), but do not have a really clear idea of what one might hope to cover or gain from it. For motivation, I am interested in elliptic curves due to potentially seeing Algebraic Geometry in action (and I am somewhat interested in Algebraic Number Theory, but am only taking a first graduate course in the material this semester).

I have gotten some reference suggestions such as: "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and Modular Forms" by Koblitz, the text by Silverman and Tate, and Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves". There were also the notes by Milne.

After an inspection of Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Chapters V on Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields and Chapter VIII with the Mordell-Weil Theorem for $\mathbb{Q}$ shine to me. However, having such a narrow goal like proving the Mordell-Weil Theorem means I will inevitably omit many other sections.

What are topics in Elliptic Curves that are essential to be aware of and should be covered in a reading course? Potentially, this may include material outside of Silverman's text.

Comment: I've done a reading course using [these](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/curves-2018/curves-2018-c7.pdf) notes.

Comment: @Don Thousand I am unsure if Gathman's chapter on elliptic curves would be sufficient for a whole reading course. Are you suggesting them as a supplement?

Comment: Yes, although his entire lecture series on plane algebraic curves is great. Certainly can be the main text for a reading course.

Comment: Proving the Mordell-Weil theorem seems like a reasonable goal for a reading course! Another goal could be to state the BSD conjecture (even the weak form): the full statement requires some understanding of elliptic curves over finite, local and global fields. Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves is a great source.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I can imagine stating BSD's weak form as an interesting idea (due to potentially providing participants an interesting unanswered question). Is the Weak BSD stated in Silverman?

Comment: There's an appendix section C.16 on it (the statement is Conj 16.5(a)), but the pre-requisites for the weak version aren't too steep: you need to know (or at least believe) that the MW group is finitely generated so that you can define the rank. To define the $L$-function, you need to understand the local story, at least at primes of good reduction.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you for the details! I will keep this in mind when I plan out aspects of the reading course.